# Android crop background

Tags: android, background, drawable, crop

I have a `LinearLayout` with width set to `fill_parent` and height to `wrap_content`. Now I want to give it a background from a png file, but doing it in a traditional way causes the `LinearLayout` to resize in order to show the whole background instead of cropping the additional part.

How can I set the background of `LinearLayout` so it won't resize?

Thanks

Comment: what is the traditional way? Could you put pictures of how its looking and how its supposed to look?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It appears that such thing is achievable only using the `ImageView` and setting the `scaleType` parameter accordingly. A quick workaround is to use `FrameLayout` and put the `ImageView` under another layout with transparent background.

Code:

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: this does not give enough detail

Comment: How to do transparent background? And does every item inform of it have to have a transparent background color?

Answer (score 6):

The default behaviour of background bitmaps is to fill the container completely and grow the horizontal and vertical size of the container if needed. The solution is to create a drawable bitmap resource and changing the gravity.

Check the following link and look for the possible gravity values. Your view should then just reference the drawable resource and you should be fine.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap

Answer (score 1):

I solved this one by subclassing `LinearLayout` and overriding the `onMeasure(int,int)` callback, then updating the layout XML to use my new layout type. I'm not at liberty to post that exact code, but what I did was invoke the `super.onMeasure(int,int)` implementation and check whether the measured height came back as the exact height of my background image. If so, I grab the measured height of all child views, then calculate a new height value and pass it to `setMeasuredDimension(int,int)`.

Answer (score -1):

put this code in the xml activity, for example activity_main.xml

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:src="@drawable/image" />
```