# android:background stretching not preserving aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-layout, background, scaling

On landscape mode my background image stretches, I would like the image to enlarge rather than stretch to fit the size. From what I've seen I have to add it to it's own layout (E.g. `LinearLayout`) or 'ImageView` and the have a layout for the content on the view, am I correct in saying this?

My current xml layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/instructions"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/photo_background"
android:tag="layout" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fadingEdge="none" >
    <include layout="@layout/instructions_internal" />
</ScrollView>
```

Which includes the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroll_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/instructionsLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent_black" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/more_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/top_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:onClick="onClickHandler" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/instructionsbutton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/test"
            android:background="@color/dark_gray"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/arrow_down_float"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:onClick="onMoreInstructions"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/more_instructions_start"
            android:textColor="@color/solid_white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/more_info"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any guidance on this would be gladly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782294/android-crop-background

Comment: So, instead of the container's **background** attribute, use an ImageView (match_parent, match_parent) **src** attribute. And set the scaleType to FIT_XY

Comment: you have put your background image on all drawable folder and also for landscape oriantation

Comment: @DerGolem Actually, I believe `FIT_XY` will do exactly the same. The OP is looking for either `CENTER_CROP` or `CENTER_INSIDE`.

Comment: @IvanBartsov: you're right, was on a hurry (lunch time), but the concept remains: Use the src of an ImageView instead of the background of the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you're correct. `View's` `background` scaling type is equivalent to `ImageView`'s `ScaleType.FIT_XY` It will mess up the aspect ratio unless you're using `wrap_content` and the contents do not make it stretch past background bounds.

So in this situation I usually use an `ImageView` I place behind the view I need to give a properly-scaled background to. (Most likely yo're looking for `CENTER_CROP` scale type)

**UPD** here's some code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/instructions"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:tag="layout" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/photo_background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fadingEdge="none" >
        <include layout="@layout/instructions_internal" />
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Brillient thanks for the update! so why would you do it in a `FrameLayout` then? Just out of interest.

Comment: @Paddy1990 `FrameLayout`'s layout logic is way simpler than that of `RelativeLayout`. So, less cycles for the CPU to spend. You were not using any of the `RelativeLayout` attributes anyway, so `FrameLayout` is the logical choice here. Also, don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: I see I never new that, learn something new everyday. Anyways, thanks a lot for the help really appreciate it. Without this site I wouldn't have got anywhere with the application. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

use an image that matches or in accordance with the android device resolution and screen size.

the image cannot itself enlarge itself, even if you use a linear layout dedicatedly for the image, the image is bound to stretch.

keep images of all possible resolutions in separate folders that you plan to run you application on.

Comment: There are that many devices and screen sizes that I would have to have 1000's of copies of the same image for it to look good on all of the devices

Comment: There's no way you could anticipate the resolution of ALL device resolutions. It's better to program for the look that you're going for.