# Triangle hole with drawable

Tags: android, overlay, crop, android-drawable

[image]

The B (white) layout is over the A (image) layout, and I need to crop the background so that I get this result.

Is that possible with drawables?
If not, what's the other solution?

Comment: Try this solution:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/7317034/1384010

Comment: "B" is just a white overlay image (9 patch) inside an ImageView, with a transparent cut in the top middle.

Comment: Thx @FrankN.Stein, maybe you could post a more detailed answer so I can validate it for the future developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the layout I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_back"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="166dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWhiteStripe"
        android:background="@drawable/white_stripe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="(B) Some text here"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#f00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

To get this result - well, just a `proof of a concept`, here: it might not be the most appealing graphics ever... ;)

[image]

The pictures I used were:

*Background* (gradient_back.png) - I could have used a single line, but... well I made a full image

[image]

and the *white stripe* (white_stripe.9.png) - which is the most interesting part in the concept

[image]

Unfortunately, it's nearly invisible, since it's all white and transparent, on a white background.

But it really looks like this one, in the 9 patch tool:

[image]

I should have restricted the content bottom padding a bit - but, well, it's easily done by removing some of the black pixels from the right side.

Enjoy.