# Crop ImageView in FrameLayout with wrap_content height

Tags: android

I would like to have image behind `TextView` in `FrameLayout`. I need `FrameLayout` to adjust it's height to `TextView` inside and not to be affected by image size. Image should be behind the text in it's original size, cropped by `FrameLayout`. This is what I tried:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:alpha="0.1"
        android:id="@+id/img_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/text_long" />

</FrameLayout>
```

It's almost what I want except the `FrameLayout`'s height is affected by image size. It should change only with text.

Comment: This is a tricky problem to solve! My initial reaction would be to have the FrameaLayout have a fixed hight while the ImageView has a height of wrap_content and then to resize the FrameLayout dynamically to match the hieght of the TextView. This solution seems like a more elegant approach (no code though, I could give it a shot in answer form if you want to see it): http://stackoverflow.com/a/21581103/6526330

Comment: @Dr.Nitpick I tried that and it wasn't working properly. If you can make it work I will gladly accept your answer.

Comment: Sure, Ill try it out tonight and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I think you can do this without overriding any layouts or writing any java code. Instead you can wrap the whole thing in a `RelativeLayout` move the `TextView` after the `FrameLayout` and set the `FrameLayout`'s top and bottom to align with the textView. I admit it is a bit messy; to address that I would recommend either making it a custom view or putting it in another xml file that you include.

Edit: Actually, you don't need the FrameLayout any more, instead you can set the android:layout_alignTop and android:layout_alignBottom attributes on the ImageView instead. Here is what it look like:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text_long"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/text_long"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:alpha="0.1"
        android:id="@+id/img_logo"/>
    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:id="@id/text_long" />
</RelativeLayout>
```